# Dificuldade em retornar o resultado em uma so query sem duplicar

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Estou tentando montar uma query (MYSQL) para me retornar todos os clientes que um determinado vendedor pode visualizar.
As regras para mostrar a lista de clientes para este vendedor são:
- Clientes com contratos vencidos ou sem contratos.
- Clientes com propostas vencidas ou sem propostas.
- Clientes com contratos vigentes ou propostas ainda na validade desde que estas tenham sido criadas pelo própria vendedor que realiza a consulta.

Resumindo: eu só posso mostrar os clientes disponíveis para este vendedor.

Meu cenário no banco de dados é:

[image: Estrutura das tabelas no meu BD]

Eu cheguei a seguinte query, mas ela está retornando clientes duplicados o problema acontece pelo fato que um cliente pode ter sido atendido por mais que um vendedor, ou seja, uma proposta vencida do vendedor 1 e um contrato vigente pelo vendedor 2, neste caso se o vendedor 2 faz a pesquisa, esse cliente aparece duas vezes no resultado, pelo fato da clausula GroupBy ter incluído tanto o registro ligado ao vendedor da tabela "Proposta" quanto quanto o registro ligado ao vendedor da tabela "Contrato".

Vejam a query:

```
    select DISTINCT  `clientes`.`id`, `clientes`.`pessoa_tipo`, `clientes`.`razao_nome`, `clientes`.`nome_fantasia`, `clientes`.`email`, `clientes`.`logradouro`, `clientes`.`numero`, `clientes`.`complemento`, `clientes`.`bairro`, `clientes`.`cidade`, `clientes`.`uf`, `clientes`.`cep`, `clientes`.`telefone`, `clientes`.`celular`, `clientes`.`cnpj_cpf`, `clientes`.`inscricao_rg`, `clientes`.`contato_nome`, `clientes`.`contato_funcao`, `clientes`.`representante_nome`, `clientes`.`representante_rg`, `clientes`.`representante_cpf`, `clientes`.`atividade_rf`, `clientes`.`atividades_comerciais_id`, `contratos`.`vendedores_id` as `contrato_vendedor`, `propostas`.`vendedores_id` as `proposta_vendedor`
from `clientes` left join `contratos` on `contratos`.`clientes_id` = `clientes`.`id` left join `propostas` on `propostas`.`clientes_id` = `clientes`.`id` 
group by `clientes`.`id`, `clientes`.`pessoa_tipo`, `clientes`.`razao_nome`, `clientes`.`nome_fantasia`, `clientes`.`email`, `clientes`.`logradouro`, `clientes`.`numero`, `clientes`.`complemento`, `clientes`.`bairro`, `clientes`.`cidade`, `clientes`.`uf`, `clientes`.`cep`, `clientes`.`telefone`, `clientes`.`celular`, `clientes`.`cnpj_cpf`, `clientes`.`inscricao_rg`, `clientes`.`contato_nome`, `clientes`.`contato_funcao`, `clientes`.`representante_nome`, `clientes`.`representante_rg`, `clientes`.`representante_cpf`, `clientes`.`atividade_rf`, `clientes`.`atividades_comerciais_id`, `contratos`.`vendedores_id`, `propostas`.`vendedores_id` 
having (Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL AND Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL)
OR
(Max(contratos.vigencia_final) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(propostas.validade) <= '2017-11-23')
OR
(Max(contratos.vigencia_final) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(propostas.validade) IS NULL)
OR
(Max(propostas.validade) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL)
OR
(contratos.vendedores_id = '3' OR propostas.vendedores_id = '3')
```

[image: Resultado da query]

Comment: Qual seria o seu cenário ideal? Você quer que não sejam exibidas propostas, somente contratos, caso haja contrato vigente para o cliente?

Comment: Quero retornar os clientes sem duplicar, no qual eu não necessito do ID do vendedor nos resultados (o que está contornado de azul, verde e vermelho)

Comment: Sendo assim, seu problema será resolvido se remover `contrato_vendedor` e `proposta_vendedor` do seu `select` e do `group by`, já que você não precisa de tais dados no resultado. Ele duplica porque há dados que tornam o registro único (os IDs dos vendedores).

Comment: mas se eu não os incluir no select não posso utilizar nas comparações do HAVING

Comment: verdade, viajei! a resposta do @marconcilio-souza faz sentido nesse caso, mas como há comparação de igualdade no caso dos ids de vendedores, acho que a melhor saida deve ser na base do subselect: um `select distinct [campos do cliente] from ([toda essa sua query]) as alias;`

Answer (score 0):

você pode retirar essas colunas do group by e usar o [Max](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html)(suacoluna) ou [Min](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-min-function.htm)(suacoluna).

Algo assim.

```
select DISTINCT  `clientes`.`id`, `clientes`.`pessoa_tipo`, `clientes`.`razao_nome`, `clientes`.`nome_fantasia`, `clientes`.`email`, `clientes`.`logradouro`, `clientes`.`numero`, `clientes`.`complemento`, `clientes`.`bairro`, `clientes`.`cidade`, `clientes`.`uf`, `clientes`.`cep`, `clientes`.`telefone`, `clientes`.`celular`, `clientes`.`cnpj_cpf`, `clientes`.`inscricao_rg`, `clientes`.`contato_nome`, `clientes`.`contato_funcao`, `clientes`.`representante_nome`, `clientes`.`representante_rg`, `clientes`.`representante_cpf`, `clientes`.`atividade_rf`, `clientes`.`atividades_comerciais_id`, 

Max(`contratos`.`vendedores_id`) as`contrato_vendedor`, 

Max(`propostas`.`vendedores_id`) as `proposta_vendedor`

from `clientes` 
left join `contratos` 
on `contratos`.`clientes_id` = `clientes`.`id` 
left join `propostas` 
on `propostas`.`clientes_id` = `clientes`.`id` 
group by `clientes`.`id`, `clientes`.`pessoa_tipo`, `clientes`.`razao_nome`, `clientes`.`nome_fantasia`, `clientes`.`email`, `clientes`.`logradouro`, `clientes`.`numero`, `clientes`.`complemento`, `clientes`.`bairro`, `clientes`.`cidade`, `clientes`.`uf`, `clientes`.`cep`, `clientes`.`telefone`, `clientes`.`celular`, `clientes`.`cnpj_cpf`, `clientes`.`inscricao_rg`, `clientes`.`contato_nome`, `clientes`.`contato_funcao`, `clientes`.`representante_nome`, `clientes`.`representante_rg`, `clientes`.`representante_cpf`, `clientes`.`atividade_rf`, `clientes`.`atividades_comerciais_id`
having (Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL AND Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL)
OR
(Max(contratos.vigencia_final) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(propostas.validade) <= '2017-11-23')
OR
(Max(contratos.vigencia_final) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(propostas.validade) IS NULL)
OR
(Max(propostas.validade) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL)
OR
(contratos.vendedores_id = '3' OR propostas.vendedores_id = '3')
```

Ou como mencionado nos comentários.

```
select * from
(
    select DISTINCT  `clientes`.`id`, `clientes`.`pessoa_tipo`, `clientes`.`razao_nome`, `clientes`.`nome_fantasia`, 
        `clientes`.`email`, `clientes`.`logradouro`, `clientes`.`numero`, `clientes`.`complemento`, `clientes`.`bairro`, 
        `clientes`.`cidade`, `clientes`.`uf`, `clientes`.`cep`, `clientes`.`telefone`, `clientes`.`celular`, `clientes`.`cnpj_cpf`, 
        `clientes`.`inscricao_rg`, `clientes`.`contato_nome`, `clientes`.`contato_funcao`, `clientes`.`representante_nome`, 
        `clientes`.`representante_rg`, `clientes`.`representante_cpf`, `clientes`.`atividade_rf`, `clientes`.`atividades_comerciais_id`, 
        `contratos`.`vendedores_id` as`contrato_vendedor`, `propostas`.`vendedores_id` as `proposta_vendedor`
    from `clientes` 
    left join `contratos` 
        on `contratos`.`clientes_id` = `clientes`.`id` 
    left join `propostas` 
        on `propostas`.`clientes_id` = `clientes`.`id` 
    group by `clientes`.`id`, `clientes`.`pessoa_tipo`, `clientes`.`razao_nome`, `clientes`.`nome_fantasia`, 
        `clientes`.`email`, `clientes`.`logradouro`, `clientes`.`numero`, `clientes`.`complemento`, `clientes`.`bairro`, 
        `clientes`.`cidade`, `clientes`.`uf`, `clientes`.`cep`, `clientes`.`telefone`, `clientes`.`celular`, `clientes`.`cnpj_cpf`, 
        `clientes`.`inscricao_rg`, `clientes`.`contato_nome`, `clientes`.`contato_funcao`, `clientes`.`representante_nome`, 
        `clientes`.`representante_rg`, `clientes`.`representante_cpf`, `clientes`.`atividade_rf`, `clientes`.`atividades_comerciais_id`,
        `contratos`.`vendedores_id`, `propostas`.`vendedores_id`
    having (Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL AND Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL)
    OR
    (Max(contratos.vigencia_final) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(propostas.validade) <= '2017-11-23')
    OR
    (Max(contratos.vigencia_final) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(propostas.validade) IS NULL)
    OR
    (Max(propostas.validade) <= '2017-11-23' AND Max(contratos.vigencia_final) IS NULL)
)
where contratos.vendedores_id = '3' 
OR propostas.vendedores_id = '3'
```

Ai você tem que ver qual resultado você espera ou precisa.

Comment: Retorna erro unknown column

Comment: Veja qual a coluna esta dando erro, veja se o nome esta correto... ou se precisa usar aspas simples com o Max()

Comment: O erro é este:  unknown column contratos.vendedores_id in having clause.

Como ele não está no SELECT, creio que isto pode ser o problema

Comment: Na realidade ele esta, mas esta com um alias... Max(`contratos`.`vendedores_id`) as`contrato_vendedor`,

Comment: então como estou usando o MAX ele não vai retornar ID baixos ( se eu tiver 3 e 8 como no exemplo... o 3 ficará de fora)

Comment: entendo, nesse caso você precisa retira do seu having e usar em um subselect .... só assim você vai consegui o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que colocar alguma função agregadora para essas colunas como por exemplo o SUM() e tirá-las do group by, ou simplesmente tirar essas colunas da sua query, depende do que qual informação você precisa que essa coluna retorne.

Comment: eu preciso coloca-las no SELECT pois preciso usa-la no HAVING afim de me retornarem os clientes que são atendidos por vendedores de tal ID.

Se não colocar por exemplo o campo "contratos.vendedores_id" o mysql retorna que esta coluna está faltando.